# visitors not being logged Matomo

Tags: matomo

I've moved my websites to a new server and at the same time moved Motomo analytics

Matomo no longer records the website visits.

The settings etc and tracking errors all show no problem

How can I find where it's not working?

Help!

Answer (score 0):

**Do you have logs registered in your Matomo database?** If your Matomo tracking code is properly installed, Matomo would record visits in your database. To check if you have logs in your database, go to Matomo > Visitors > Visits log, and select “today” in the calendar. If you see recent visitor information, it means that the visitor tracking is working, but maybe there is a problem with reports archiving.

**If you see visits in the Visits Log, then please check your archiving works correctly.**
Review our doc here: https://matomo.org/docs/setup-auto-archiving/

**If you are not seeing visits in the Visit log,** then there is an issue with the data tracking. Please check this FAQ for more information and steps to troubleshoot: https://matomo.org/faq/troubleshooting/faq_58/